# Value Converter set in Style does not get file value, but whole datarow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I set up a style for a label which should be triggered if the value of the bound filed in the underlying `DataTable` is greater than zero:

```
<c:Groesser0BooleanValueConverter x:Key="G0" />

<Style x:Key="DashboardProzent" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource G0}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

The label itself is set up this way (a DataTemplate in a resource Dictionary):

```
<Label Content="{Binding percentCol}" Style="{StaticResource DashboardPrzoent}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

The converter looks like this:

```
public class Groesser0BooleanValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToInt32(value) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If a run the whole thing, i get the error in the `Convert` method of the Groesser0BooleanValueConverter  class:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'

If I check the parameter of the Convert method of the Converter, it shows that a `System.Data.DataRowView` has been passed, instead of the value of the percentCol field, which I would have expected. How can I get the Label to pass the value instead of the whole row?

Update:

If I set the `Label` to

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=percentCol}" Style="{StaticResource DashboardPrzoent}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

the error still occurs. If I disable the trigger, the value is shown (even without the `Path=` segment.

I don't want to state the field name in the style segment, as I would like to use it for other values to.

Comment: bind expected value properly: `{Binding Path=percentCol, Converter={StaticResource G0}}`. DataRow/DataRowView/DataTable - there is no a single hint of them in the shown code. you cannot solve a problem with all code in place, and how should others help you solve it without [mcve]??

Comment: What exactly are you missing? As mentionend the value of the field percentCol is shown fine, as long as the trigger/converter are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to set the `Binding Path` and the `Binding Converter` in two different locations, for example a `DataTemplate` and a `Style` file.

This can be done by using `{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource converterName}}` in the `Style` and setting the `Binding Path` as usual in the `DataTemplate`

Converter

```
<Style x:Key="DashboardPrzoent" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource G0}}"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Gruen}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource G0}}"  Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Rot}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

DataTemplate

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=percentCol}"  ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think the main problem is due to your `Binding` in the `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource G0}}" Value="{x:Null}">
```

This will pass on the direct `DataContext` of your `Label` to your `Converter`, which is obviously not what you want.
You should have:

```
<DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource G0}, Path=percentCol}" Value="False">
```

I also corrected the `Value` part, since your 'Converter' only sends back `True/False`. If you want to change back to `Value="{x:Null}"`, you will have to modify your converter.

I would also advise to be safer in your `Converter`, otherwise the explicit conversion `System.Convert.ToInt32(value)` may (will...) raise an error.